# Remove row in Pyspark data frame that contains less than n word

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a **Pyspark dataframe** consisting of about 6 Million lines. The dataset has the following structure:

```
root
 |-- content: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------+-----+
|               text |score|
+--------------------+-----+
|word word hello d...|    5|
|hi man how are yo...|    5|
|come on guys let ...|    5|
|do you like some ...|    1|
|accept              |    1|
+--------------------+-----+
```

Is there a way to remove all lines that contain only sentences of at least 4 words in length? In order to delete all the lines with a few words. 
I did it this way, but it takes a long time:

```
pandasDF = df.toPandas()
cnt = 0
ind = []
for index, row in pandasDF.iterrows():
  txt = row["text"]
  spl = txt.split()
  if((len(spl)) < 4):
    ind.append(index)
    cnt += 1

pandasDF = pandasDF.drop(labels=ind, axis=0)
```

Is there a way to do this **faster** and **without** turning my Pyspark dataframe into a Pandas data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `text` can be split into single words with [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) and the number of words can then be counted with [size](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.size.html):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.filter( F.size(F.split('text', ' ')) >= 4).show()
```

This statements keeps only rows that contain at least 4 words.

Comment: work! BUT when I'm go to count the number of row that I've obtained the code return me this error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'"

Comment: remove the `show()` in my answer and replace it with `count()`.